# How to query the status/progress of a Hadoop mapreduce job from Python

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I'd like to query the status and progress of mapreduce jobs. Meaning that I need to list all the jobs and job details. Is there any API that I can use from Python. If not, what alternative do I have? Thanks.